# SQL Left Join only returning matching records

Tags: sql

I have a table with 300+ records I am trying to join with another, instead of returning all records with the second tables matching records included,it only returns matching records.

Table vtRawDayData can have in it's StopPlaceIDs varchar field, null, a single ID in the form P12C1234 or multiple ID's P12C1234, P12C2345....

Table tblPools has a varchar ID field and an integer ServiceLevel_ID field

I want to return all 300+ records from the vtRawDayData Table with the ServiceLevel_ID where
there is an exact match to a single ID. So records with null or multiple ID's will have a null value in the ServiceLevel_ID field.

What I have with just pertinent fields:

```
Select 
  rdd.Vehicle,
  rdd.Date,
  rdd.StartLocation,
  rdd.StartGeoFence,
  rdd.StartPlaceIDs,
  rdd.StartLatitude,
  rdd.StartLongitude,
  rdd.StartTime,
  rdd.TravelTime,
  rdd.StopLocation,
  rdd.StopGeoFence,
  rdd.StopPlaceIDs,
  rdd.StopLatitude,
  rdd.StopLongitude,
  rdd.ArrivalTime,
  rdd.StopDuration,
  rdd.StopDurationSeconds,
  rdd.IdleDuration,
  rdd.DepartureTime,
  rdd.Odometer,
  rdd.IdleTimeSeconds,
  rdd.StopDurationSeconds / 60 as StopDurationMinutes,
  p.ServiceLevel_ID 

FROM
  vtRawDayData rdd 

LEFT JOIN
  tblPools p 

WHERE
  rdd.StopPlaceIDs = p.ID
```

This only returns 99 Exact matching records. I just want to add the ServiceLevel_ID to the records with a single ID in the StopPlaceIDs field

What am I missing?

Comment: You have `WHERE` clause that involves "right" table that effectively make it an INNER JOIN. Instead use `ON` clause.

Comment: `LEFT JOIN tblPools p ON rdd.StopPlaceIDs = p.ID`

Comment: `LEFT JOIN   tblPools p ON   rdd.StopPlaceIDs = p.ID`

Comment: In SQL NULL is not equal to ***anything***, including another NULL.

Answer (score 0):

Posted this after working on it for some time, getting sample data into my program from a .csv file while in design mode was time consuming. Then went in the shower and it came to me. I was hoping to get back before anyone saw it:)

Thanks